# Issues about this error: "Error in $.shinyoutput: Reading from shinyoutput object is not allowed."

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to prepare a Shinyapp with pre-loaded data. Among other question that I have (I'm a nooby right now), I want to kindly ask why is this error keep occurring. Here is my code, I have no idea what else should I have to say, but I really hope your expertise will resolve this problem. This is my script:

UI.

```
min<-min(reportesFGE2$Fecha_Registro)
max<-max(reportesFGE2$Fecha_Registro)


ui <- fluidPage(
titlePanel("Delitos"),
sidebarPanel(

dateRangeInput(inputId = "fecha_r",
               label= "Fecha de registro",
               min = Sys.Date() - 5, max = Sys.Date() + 5),

selectInput(inputId = "nivel",
            label= "Nivel", 
            multiple = F,
            choices = c("Nacional"=1, "Provincial"=2)),

selectizeInput(inputId = "provincia",
               label= "provincia", 
               multiple = T,
               choices = as.character(unique(reportesFGE2$pro_descripcion))),

selectInput(inputId = "tipo_delito1",
            label= "Presunto delito", 
            multiple = T,
            choices = as.character(unique(reportesFGE2$Presunto_Delito)))),
mainPanel( plotOutput("plot1"))
)
```

and this is SERVER.

```
server <- function(input, output) {


output$plot1 <- renderPlot({

if (req(output$nivel)==1) {

  reportesFGE2$anio<-substring(reportesFGE2$Fecha_Registro,1,4)
  x<- subset(reportesFGE2,Presunto_Delito==input$tipo_delito
             &Fecha_Registro>=input$fecha_r[1]&Fecha_Registro<=input$fecha_r[2])
  y <- x %>% count(x$Presunto_Delito, x$anio)


  p1<-plot(y$n~y$`x$anio`,
           type="o",
           main="Número de delitos por año\n(hasta septiembre de 2019)",
           xlab=input$tipo_delito,
           ylab="Número de delitos")


} else  if (req(output$nivel)==2) {

  selectedData <- reactive({
    req(input$fecha_r[1])
    req(input$fecha_r[2])
    req(input$tipo_delito)
    req(input$provincia)
    reportesFGE2 %>%
      dplyr::filter( Fecha_Registro >= input$fecha_R[1]
                     & Fecha_Registro <= input$fecha_R[2]
                     &pro_descripcion %in% input$provincia
                    & Presunto_Delito %in% input$tipo_delito)
  })


  output$plot1 <-renderPlot({
    x==selectedData()
    x$anio<-substring(x$Fecha_Registro,1,4)
    y <- x %>% count(x$Presunto_Delito, x$anio)


    p1<-plot(y$n~y$`x$anio`,
             type="o",
             main="Número de delitos por año\n(hasta septiembre de 2019)",
             xlab=input$tipo_delito,
             ylab="Número de delitos")
  })      
}
 })
 }
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot test it because your code sample is not reproducible. But what the error states is that you are trying to access an UI output variable directly in your server. Of course you can access the generated `output` in your server, but then it becomes an `input`, right?

This happens when you are checking if `output$nivel` is either 1 or 2. You should access the `nivel` variable with `input$nivel` in your server.